# Searching two column fields using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I want to search using PersalNumber or IdNumber and it gave me an error that says:

*No overload for method 'Where' takes 2 arguments*

I have schema consisting of PersalNumber and IdNumber

- PersalNumber stores a work number
- IdNumber stores numbers of passport or driving license etc
- Teachers is a table name

> Below is the code I use for searching both the fields.

```
    public ActionResult PopulateResult(string search)
    {
        return View(db.teachers.Where(x=>x.PersalNumber.Contains(search), s=>s.IdNumber.Contains(search)).ToList());
    }
```

I want to know is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust your condition like below

```
db.teachers.Where(x => x.PersalNumber.Contains(search) || 
                       x.IdNumber.Contains(search)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the || (or) operator between the two conditions.

```
return View(db.teachers.Where(x=>x.PersalNumber.Contains(search) ||  
                                 x.IdNumber.Contains(search)).ToList())
```

and you should make the comparison using the *x* argument not this undefined *s*
Note, this should work correctly if both PersonalNumber and IdNumber are strings.

Comment: Hi, @Jpi Champ This answer looks good with a well explanation. You should consider accepting it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers